# PRs that were assigned to my team to be reviewed

Tags: github, pull-request

How I can find PRs that were assigned to my team to be reviewed including those that have already been reviewed by someone in my team but its still open. Preferably in Github UI/CLI through some filter or search.

Found a link mentioning something similar to this issue, https://github.com/dear-github/dear-github/issues/306

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by "team". Are you referring to actual [_GitHub Teams_](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/organizing-members-into-teams/about-teams) - or are you referring to your GitHub Organization (which presumably contains your real-life teammates?)

Comment: I meant PRs assigned to the team within my organisation, https://github.com/orgs/<org-name>/teams/<team-name>, so it can be identified by <org-name>/<team-name>